# button border width in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to display four buttons with their borders touching each other and the borders between the buttons being smaller than the borders facing the outside. However, I can't find an option to set individual Border Widths for each of the buttons side. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.33*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.33*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="-3">
        <Button x:Name="frame6" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="2" CornerRadius="0" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference frame6}}">
        </Button>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-3">
        <Button BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="2" CornerRadius="0" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference frame6}}">
        </Button>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="-3">
        <Button BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1" CornerRadius="0" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference frame6}}">
        </Button>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-3">
        <Button BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1" CornerRadius="0" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference frame6}}">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You can't directly do this, can you show me what you want may be i can help you do it

Comment: If you want to touch a button and scale it to bigger, that's what you need to add button. 
  xct:TouchEffect.AnimationDuration="250"
                    xct:TouchEffect.AnimationEasing="{x:Static Easing.CubicInOut}"
                    xct:TouchEffect.PressedScale="1.25"
                    xct:TouchEffect.PressedBackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                    xct:TouchEffect.NormalBackgroundColor="Transparent"

Comment: You said the borders between the buttons being smaller than the borders facing the outside， which specific border do you mean? Can you help edit your post to show this issue?